# Cumulative Distribution Function for a Certain range

Tags: probability, statistics

For the question:

Consider a random variable $X$ with probability density function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \ell &\text{if }x\in[2,5]\\ 2\ell &\text{if }x\in(5,8] \\0 &\text{otherwise }\end{cases}$$

with $\ell$ as $\frac{1}{9}$

Determine the cumulative distribution function $F_X(t)$.

---

My answers for the following ranges are as follows:

$i)\text{ } For \text{ }t\in (-\infty,2), \text{ }F_X(t) = 0$

$ii)\text{ }  For \text{ }t\in [2,5), \text{ }F_X(t) = \frac{1}{3}$

$iii)\text{ }  For \text{ }t\in (5,8], \text{ }F_X(t) = \frac{2}{3}$

$iv)\text{ }  For \text{ }t\in (8,-\infty), \text{ }F_X(t) = 1$

All these answers were determined by $F_X(t)=\int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$ however the marking system indicates that 2 out of the 4 answers are incorrect.

I suspect that the answers for ii) and iii) are incorrect due to calculating the integrals with the wrong ranges however after consulting the page [Expected Values and CDF](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442727/expected-values-and-cdf?answertab=votes#tab-top) and rectifying my answers to:

$ii\text{ } rectified)\text{ }  For \text{ }t\in [2,5), \text{ }F_X(t) = \frac{x^2-2}{9}$

$iii\text{ } rectified)\text{ }  For \text{ }t\in (5,8], \text{ }F_X(t) = \frac{16-2x^2}{9}$

it still marks the answers wrong.

**Can somebody please clarify on why these answers are incorrect and let me know how the question should be correctly approached?**

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not integrating correctly $F_X(t)$ for $t\in(2,8)$,  $\ell\cdot\int_2^t dx=l(t-2)$, $t\in(2,5]$. You should figure out why you wrongly get a $t^2$.